# Why does this PHP Framework display the directory index rather than the webpage?

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

Since this is a problem that is related to an entire project which is finished, I do not think I will be able to post the entire code. If any additional information is needed, please ask and I will edit this.

I have a website that was developed for one of my classes using this PHP Framework: https://github.com/panique/mini. This website works on a server that I rented from HostGator (which provided me with a LAMP stack) and I am now trying to move the website to an AWS EC2 instance.

I have setup an AWS EC2 using the documentation and tutorial provided by Amazon and am able to successfully host webpages from my instance after installing the LAMP stack. The PHP Framework that I am using requires PHP 5.3+ which I have on my EC2 instance. I have also set up MySql correctly and I am able to access my databases using MySql Workbench.

I have uploaded the project files onto the public directory where the webpages are served which is `var/www/html/`. and have configured the `config.php` file correctly with my MySql information (it's the exact same login credentials as I used for MySql Workbench).

So now onto the problem I am experiencing. Whenever I browse to mydomain.com/Project (let's say the project is in `var/www/html/Project`) I get the directory index rather than the web application that I developed. From what I read in the Github readme, the PHP Framework should work after configuring the MySql database information in `config/config.php`. I know that this is correctly configured because I am able to make calls to the database tables.

Has anyone had any experience with this PHP Framework? This is the first time I have actually set up a LAMP stack in Amazon Linux. I was wondering if there are any configuration settings related to Apache that I should have configured?

Comment: do you have an `index.php`? because that's what happens when you don't have an `index.php`

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Yes, the `index.php` is in the `public` folder within the PHP Framework that I used.

Comment: yeah... you have to have one in the *main* folder. the one where you currently get the directory index instead.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann The way the PHP Framework I am using has one in the `public` folder which is within `var/www/html/Project` directory. Im not exactly sure what I would put in the new `index.php` for the main folder.

Comment: If this helps, there is an `.htaccess` that defines '# This file is - if you set up MINI correctly - not needed.
# But, for fallback reasons (if you don't route your vhost to /public), it will stay here.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]'

Comment: A PHP framework has no way to trigger Apache mod_dir (even intentionally). If that happens, you know for sure that PHP has not been called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New frameworks today separated `/public` directory for request accessible.

You have option to

**1. Point your apache to `/public`**
edit fie `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` (depend on distribution).
and change

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

to

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/myframework/public"
```

you can also do this with VirtualHost or Alias.

**2. Using .htaccess + mod_rewrite to framework's root directory.**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**3. Add an index.php file to your framework's root directory.**

```
<?php
header('Location: public/');

// This option is not really fix the problem. it's just redirect user to    `/public`. you will always have `/public` in your urls.

// It's only work for home page. 
// You can use only relative path to your assets.
```

Comment: Interesting, this solved the directory index problem but now I have the problem that none of the files in the actual `public` folder are being accessed correctly. For example the `mydomain.com/Project/js/` does not exist. The correct URL should be `mydomain.com/Project/public/js`. All of the files in the `public` folder are returning with a `404` because of this malformed URL. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Which option did you choose?

Comment: I chose the 3rd option and got the page to load. Everything seems fine except for loading assets in the `public` folder.

Comment: yes, you will have this kind of problem with option 3. You can only use relative path for your assets. You can not use absolute path. I added note to  the answer.